# SQL Server 2008 GET DATETIMEOFFSET according to machine settings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

On SQL Server 2008 R2, I have following T-SQL code:

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIMEOFFSET);
```

This gives me the result as below:

> 2011-12-26 10:21:13.7970000 +00:00

But the result is what I wanted to be. It should be this:

> 2011-12-26 10:21:13.7970000 **+02:00**

Here is my machine's *Date and Time Settings*:

[image]

The same thing happens while I am inserting a value:

```
DECLARE @foo AS TABLE(
    fooDate DATETIMEOFFSET
);

INSERT @foo VALUES(GETDATE());

SELECT * FROM @foo;
```

This gets me the same wrong result (at least wrong for my needs).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();
```

`GETDATE()` function has no any timezone information