# How to convert a DateTime string to a DateTime in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime-format

I have a DateTime varchar in this format: 2005-08-08T00:00:00+01:00.

1. Does this format have a name? (it's not ISO8601. Is it RFC3339?)
2. How can I convert it to a DateTime using Transact-Sql?

**EDIT**
Here's a summary answer, cobbled together from others input:

1. It *is* ISO8601 with a time offset from UTC. If it was UTC it would end with a 'Z' instead of '+01:00'.  [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)
2. You can convert it to local time or to utc as follows:

   > DECLARE @d VARCHAR(25) SET @d = '2007-08-08T00:01:00+01:00' SET @d =
   >   '2007-08-08T00:01:00-01:00' SET @d = '2007-08-08T00:01:00+05:30'
   >
   > SELECT @d as Input, CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@d, 19), 126) AS LocalDate
   >   , DATEADD(MINUTE  , -CAST((SUBSTRING(@d, 20, 1) + RIGHT(@d, 2)) AS
   >   INT)  , DATEADD(HOUR 
   >          ,-CAST(SUBSTRING(@d, 20, 3) AS INT)
   >          , CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@d, 19), 126))) as UtcDate WHERE @d LIKE '**_*-***-_T__:**:**[+-]**:**'

Results:

```
Input                     LocalDate               UtcDate
------------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2007-08-08T00:01:00+01:00 2007-08-08 00:01:00.000 2007-08-07 23:01:00.000

2007-08-08T00:01:00-01:00 2007-08-08 00:01:00.000 2007-08-08 01:01:00.000

2007-08-08T00:01:00+05:30 2007-08-08 00:01:00.000 2007-08-07 18:31:00.000
```

Comment: Yes, I found that page using google. Couldn't find my format in there though.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that your SUBSTRING() statement removes the minutes component of the timezone, meaning it will be incorrect in timezones that aren't whole hours relative to UTC. e.g. India which is UTC+5:30.

Comment: oh, also if the format is something like 2005-08-08T00:00:00-01:00, i.e. the offset is minus instead of positive, your result will be incorrect.

Comment: Rory - I have edited the sql to calculate the utc correctly when timezones aren't whole hours, but I can't see anything wrong with the calculation when offset is minus - see the results above

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SQL Server **2008** you can use the `datetimeoffset` data type.

```
SELECT [Result] = CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2005-08-08T00:01:00+01:00', 127)
```

Output:

```
Result
----------------------------------
2005-08-08 00:01:00.0000000 +01:00
```

---

In SQL Server **2005** and earlier you can compute the UTC date and offset:

```
SELECT [LocalDate], [OffsetMinutes], [UtcDate]
FROM
(
    SELECT [IsoDate] = '2007-08-08T00:01:00+01:00'
) A
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT [LocalDate] = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([IsoDate], 19), 126)
    , [OffsetMinutes] =
        CASE SUBSTRING([IsoDate], 20, 1)
            WHEN '+' THEN +1
            WHEN '-' THEN -1
        END
        * DATEDIFF(minute, 0,
            CAST(SUBSTRING([IsoDate], 21, 5) + ':00' AS datetime))
    WHERE [IsoDate] LIKE '____-__-__T__:__:__[+-]__:__'
) B
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT [UtcDate] = DATEADD(minute, -[OffsetMinutes], [LocalDate])
) C
```

Output:

```
LocalDate               OffsetMinutes UtcDate
----------------------- ------------- -----------------------
2007-08-08 00:01:00.000 60            2007-08-07 23:01:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks, but the database is Sql Server 2005, and I need to convert it to a DateTime

Comment: Of course, you are correct. I cannot convert all the information in the string directly to a DateTime. The timezone has to be stored elsewhere (if it's needed)

Comment: Ok. I've added a solution for SQL Server 2005

Comment: Wow! There's a lot going on here, but the main thing I just realised is that @bluefeet and I have been adding the timezone when we should be subtracting it!

Answer (score 3):

Its ISO8601 with time zone Z

use

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2005-08-08T00:00:00',126)
```

see
[MSDN Explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

EDIT:
I think it something to do with the zone on the end I originally assumed tSql would accept that but turns out it wont.

Comment: just tested this in sql server 2005 and 2008 and it fails

Comment: Wow thats strange considering `SELECT CONVERT(date,'2005-08-08T00:00:00+01:00',127) does work

Comment: I expect date would work because it ignores the timezone when datetime doesn't, and I should have specified Sql Server 2005. "Type date is not a defined system type." in 2005

Comment: Well that link above mentions something about the 127 type but does not indicate it wouldn't convert to datetime...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it a really ugly way, where you get the date first, then get the time and add the offset as hour:

```
declare @d varchar(50)
set @d = '2005-08-08T00:00:00+01:00'

select Convert(datetime, left(@d, 10)) 
    + DateAdd(hour, Cast(substring(@d, 21, 2) as int), convert(datetime, substring(@d, 12, 8)))
```

or a consolidated version:

```
SELECT DateAdd(hour, Cast(substring(@d, 21, 2) as int), CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@d, 19) ,127))

Final Result:
2005-08-08 01:00:00.000
```

if you don't need the offset, then:

```
declare @d varchar(50)
set @d = '2005-08-08T00:00:00+01:00'

select Convert(datetime, left(@d, 10)) 
    +  convert(datetime, substring(@d, 12, 8))

Result:
2005-08-08 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thinking about this, and the answer from Anthony Faull. The string contains the datetime and the timezone but Sql Server 2005 can only store the DateTime. So I have to drop the timezone, or convert it to the timezone I've decided to store DateTimes in (GMT)

Comment: And this is a more succinct way of doing it: SELECT DateAdd(hour, Cast(substring(@d, 21, 2) as int), CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@d, 19) ,127)). I suggest you edit your answer...

Comment: The consolidated one is the one I used. It converts the time to GMT for storing in the database (I lose the time zone it was set in, but that's ok). Thanks

Comment: Be careful here. The consolidated version should subtract the offset, not add it

Answer (score 0):

Per the selected answer, datetimeoffset is a good solution.  However, be careful sql server side with built in functions.
(I tried to paste this as a comment to the accepted answer, but it would not format the code sample)

```
select GETDATE(), CONVERT(datetimeoffset, GETDATE(), 127), CONVERT(varchar, convert(datetimeoffset, getdate(), 127)) 
-- Ugg! a SQL Server Bug!!!
-- 2013-08-16 12:54:54.090  2013-08-16 12:54:54.0900000 +00:00  2013-08-16 12:54:54.0900000 +0

select GETUTCDATE(),convert( datetimeoffset, GETUTCDATE(), 127), convert(varchar, convert( datetimeoffset, GETUTCDATE(), 127)) 
-- 2013-08-16 16:54:54.090  2013-08-16 16:54:54.0900000 +00:00  2013-08-16 16:54:54.0900000 +0
```

Comment: If the problem you are demonstrating is that the string has been truncated when you convert to a varchar, then that is because you have not specified the length of the varchar and sql server defaults to 30 characters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: Actually, what I was trying to demonstrate is that GETDATE() converted with datetimeoffset applies 00:00 instead of the correct timezone format.  You can use datediff between GETDATE() and GETUTCDATE() and build the string manually, but one would think that SQL Server would handle the offset correctly in conversion when using convert with mode 127.

Comment: Sql server cannot infer the offset when converting from a datetime to a datetimeoffset because that information is not stored in the datetime structure. You need the SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() function. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8634229/150342

Comment: Learn something new every day :)  I wasn't aware of that function, but I will surely use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `datetime2` output

```sql
declare @dof datetimeoffset;
set @dof = cast('2005-08-08T00:00:00+01:00' as datetimeoffset);
select dateadd(minute, datepart(tzoffset, @dof), cast(@dof as datetime2));

-- returns 2005-08-08 01:00:00.0000000
```