# How to convert string contain timezone to datetime sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime-format

I have string that contain date time value 2014-09-09T10:30:04+0700 and i want to convert to datetime format in SQL Server

previously i try with this query, but it doesn't works

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-03-01T10:30:04+0700', 126)
CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2014-03-01T10:30:04+0700', 127)
```

how to convert the string to sql server datetime format?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: You want to convert to `datetime` or `datetimeoffset`?

Comment: This is Answered in the Following link .. Please check 
[Check here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300647/how-to-convert-a-datetime-string-to-a-datetime-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-03-01T10:30:04+0700', 126)` fails because of the `Timezone` offset:

```
+0700
```

So, you need to use `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` to remove that, like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT('2014-03-01T10:30:04+0700',19), 126)
```

And the `CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2014-03-01T10:30:04+0700', 127)` also fails because your `Timezone` offset is wrong, namely:

From

```
+0700
```

it should be

```
+07:00
```

Comment: This is the only way to go

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server wants a colon in the tz offset. You can do:

```
CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, LEFT('2014-03-01T10:30:04+0700',22) + ':00')
```

but you need to be sure the tz offset is there. The offset should always end if 00 but if not you need to be a little more clever and get the last 2 digits as well.